# why isn't my listview refreshed in xamarin.android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, refresh, adapter

Hello I have the following code

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    Button b;
    Button c;
    TextView t;
    List<string> tasks = new List<string>();
    ListView lView;
    ArrayAdapter<string> adapter;
    int count = 0;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        b = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn);
        c = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.clearBtn);
        t = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tView);
        lView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1,tasks);

        lView.Adapter = adapter;
        b.Click += ChangeTextAndAdd;
    }
}
private void ChangeTextAndAdd(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    t.Text = "text is changed";
    string listItem = string.Format("task{0}", count++);
    tasks.Add(listItem);

    adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();

 }
```

My question is why doesn't my listview update when I click on my button. I don't understand it because I have used `adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();` but it doesn't work. Is there something I've been missing?

Comment: try this `listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: doesn't work either. Could this be due to a bug in Visual Studio? Because I have tired  `NotifyDataSetChaged()` before and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code only add the item to the list, but doesn't update the array adapter:

```
tasks.Add(listItem);
```

Either add the item directly to the adapter:

```
adapter.Add(listItem);
```

or after you add the item to the list, clear the adapter and re-add the list to it:

```
adapter.Clear();
adapter.Add(tasks);
```

Comment: It works, but I don't get it. Doesn't  `adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1,tasks);` mirror every item from the list in the adapter? And when I refresh it shouldn't it just walkthrough all the items in the list? If I add them directly to the adapter the list becomes useless.

Comment: @GeorgiYakov When you initialize adapter, it just put the items from the list you've passed to it to it's own ones. It is not aware of the changes made to your list of items anymore.

Comment: but what happens then when I use `adapter.NotifyDataSetChaged()`. Doesn't it refresh the adapter when I have already added the new item to the list?

Comment: when you add the new item, you only added it to the list. the array adapter's own list already disconnected from your original list. so if you don't add the item directly to the adapter and called `NotifyDataSetChanged()`, the adapter's list value is still the original one.